# How to update(previous value + new value) value of dictionary against same key in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dictionary

I want to update(previous value + new value) the value of dictionary against same key but it doesn't work.In my code it just replace with new value. How i do this ? Please help .

```
if (itemIdTextBox.Text != String.Empty || quantityTextBox.Text != String.Empty)
{
   string ProductId = itemIdTextBox.Text;
   int ProductQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(quantityTextBox.Text);
   if (aShop.aProducts.ContainsKey(ProductId))
   {
       aShop.aProducts[ProductId] = ProductQuantity;
   }
   else
   {
        aShop.aProducts.Add(ProductId,ProductQuantity);
   }
}
```

I want if next time dictionary get any key which is exists then it just change value(previous value + new value) else if it create new key and value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `aProducts` be a KeyValuePair, then `aProducts[SomeKey]` points to the value(Let's assume that this is the previous value) then you can do a `+=` operation to update the value(existing value + current Value = Updated value) See the code for this:

```
aShop.aProducts[ProductId] += ProductQuantity;
```

Comment: Thanks. It's Work!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the same for all element of the Dictionary, you can do that:

```
aShop.aProducts = aShop.aProducts.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value + ProductQuantity);
```